# File naming with python in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I just transferred from c++ to python as i'm still learning. I tried making simple gui but i happen to encounter this problem in naming a file. can someone give me a solution? Here is my code below

```
directory = "C:/ElcidProjects/Bills

    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)

    filename = str(directory)+"Batch Number: "+str(LabelBatchEntry.get())+".rtf"
    f= open(filename +"a")
```

and this is the error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

Having tried things in order to work i encountered another problem which is this

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/ElcidProjects/Bills/Batch Number:15.rtfa'
```

now im getting nowhere from solving this problem :

[[image: Image of the Error][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxNjj.png)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: For Tkinter, I often open a terminal in current directory, and run the file in terminal for example by entering `filename.py`. Also, it is useful to `print(type())` to check the variable type. tuple is an un-editable array, marked by `()`; list is like an array `[]`

Comment: I don't think it's possible for that code to give that error, no matter what `directory` and `LabelBatchEntry.get()` return.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the full traceback you're getting to — there isn't enough information and code in it now.

Comment: If `directory` does not exist, then you create one.  How do you expect to open file from a newly created directory which should contain no file inside?  Also `:` may not be a valid character in a filename.  And should `f= open(filename +"a")` be `f= open(filename, "a")`?  Also in your linked image, `f= open(filename + "a")` is in the editor window, but the error is `f= open(filename +"w")`, strange!

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking your LabelBatchEntry.get() returns tuple, not str. as it said in the error,

You should only concatenate tuple to tuple. You'd better type following code to see

what is type of LabelBatchEntry.get().

`print(type(LabelBatchEntry.get()))`

Comment: they are explicitly converting the value of `LabelBatchEntry.get()` to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Change line 141 to

```py
f=open(filename,"a")
```